# OAN - Aion staking pool - putting blocksigner in a docker container

Tags: java, docker, blockchain, aion, oan

I am trying to put blocksigner.jar into a separate docker container for automated deployments - however I keep getting this error:

```
 java -jar block_signer.jar -config config.properties
[2019-11-15T13:44:32.716Z] Retrieving the coinbase address from the StakerRegistry at a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
[2019-11-15T13:44:32.834Z] eth_call payload: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"to" : "0xa000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","data" : "0x210012676574436f696e626173654164647265737322a0e79df21eaec4e1691b45415ec4f536dd393669ad4074c3a8096147230cc634"},"latest"],"id":1}
[2019-11-15T13:44:32.886Z] eth_call response: InternalRpcResult { unsuccessful due to: unknown error }
Exception in thread "main" org.aion.avm.userlib.abi.ABIException: Tried to decode from a null or empty data field.
        at org.aion.avm.userlib.abi.ABIDecoder.checkNullEmptyData(ABIDecoder.java:803)
        at org.aion.avm.userlib.abi.ABIDecoder.decodeOneAddress(ABIDecoder.java:465)
        at org.aion.staker.BlockSigner.getCoinbaseAddress(BlockSigner.java:174)
        at org.aion.staker.BlockSigner.main(BlockSigner.java:77)
```

I am wondering if I am missing a dependency, or why would do I keep running into this?

I am able to run the blocksigner fine when I run it in the same container with the node.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your docker is not blocking rpc request?

Comment: How should I do that? As you can guess, I am relatively new to docker.